# How can i get the specific array using Lodash in react js

Tags: lodash, reactjs, material-ui, babeljs

How can i get the specific array using Lodash in react js ?
I have an array of objects, 10 topUsers.

```
data:{
 "topUsers":[
   {
      "user":"foo"
   },
   {
      "user":"bar"
   },
   {
      "user":"mike"
   },
   {
      "user":"jen"
   },
   {
      "user":"carl"
   },
   {
      "user":"ben"
   },
   {
      "user":"tony"
   },
   {
      "user":"mark"
   },
   {
      "user":"peter"
   },
   {
      "user":"jake"
   }
]}
```

and I want to display start from top 5 which is "user":"carl", assume the {idx} is the index of array

I'am try to use the _.map for mapping the data, but for specific index or array I dont have any idea.

```
<TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false} style={{minHeight: 65}}>
{ _.map(this.state.data.topUsers, (users, idx) => { return(
<TableRow displayBorder={true}>
    <TableRowColumn style={{height: 75 , textAlign: 'center'}}>{idx + 1}</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn style={{ justifyContent: 'center', textAlign: 'center' , paddingLeft: '5px' }}>
        <Col xs={12}>
            <Row>
                <Col xs={4} style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <label style={{whiteSpace: 'normal', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis'}}>
                        {_.get(users, 'users', ' ')}
                    </label>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Col>
    </TableRowColumn>
</TableRow>) })}
```

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with your JSON structure. The top level should be an object, not an array.

Comment: Oppps sorry I try to edit now the data array :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#slice` (or lodash's equivalent) to slice the array from an index to the end. So `arr.slice(4)`, will create a new array from the 5th (0 based) item to the end.

Btw - if you want the 5 top items, you need to slice from index 5. Slicing from the 4th index will give you 6 items.

For example:

```js
const topUsers = [{"user":"foo"},{"user":"bar"},{"user":"mike"},{"user":"jen"},{"user":"carl"},{"user":"ben"},{"user":"tony"},{"user":"mark"},{"user":"peter"},{"user":"jake"}];

const result = topUsers.slice(5)
  .map(({ user }) => user); // whatever you want to map user into

console.log(result);
```

And in your case:

```
<TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false} style={{minHeight: 65}}>
{ this.state.data.topUsers.slice(5).map((users, idx) => { return(
<TableRow displayBorder={true}>
    <TableRowColumn style={{height: 75 , textAlign: 'center'}}>{idx + 1}</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn style={{ justifyContent: 'center', textAlign: 'center' , paddingLeft: '5px' }}>
        <Col xs={12}>
            <Row>
                <Col xs={4} style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <label style={{whiteSpace: 'normal', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis'}}>
                        {_.get(users, 'users', ' ')}
                    </label>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Col>
    </TableRowColumn>
</TableRow>) })}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `_.slice(array, [start=0], [end=array.length])`
To learn more, see [enter link description here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#slice)

Comment: Hi im still new in lodash _.slice(idx, start=4, end= ?) is this correct ?

Comment: end is your arr position(this position begin 1 not 0), eg, var a = [1,2,3,4,5]. 
_slice(a, 2,3), it will return [3].